# Integrate flink environment with hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-flink, flink-table-api

Hi I am trying to integrate my flink environment with hive.
I am using flink 1.15.1 and hive 1.1
I read in the flink doc [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/connectors/table/hive/overview/#dependencies) that I need to add to the /lib directory the `flink-sql-connector-hive-1.2.2` so I added that on the flink official docker image using costume dockerfile.

The second part they ask is setting the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` environment variable.
I did not understand what should be in the path I give in. configuratio to hadoop? (core-site.xml, hive-site.xml etc..) Should I add hadoop to the image?

Is there anything else I need to do in order to integrate my flink environment with hive?
And where should all the hadoop site.xml configuration be?

DockerFile:

```
FROM flink:1.15.1-java11

COPY oshi-core-3.4.0.jar /opt/flink/lib
COPY jna-5.4.0.jar /opt/flink/lib
COPY jna-platform-5.4.0.jar /opt/flink/lib

COPY flink-sql-connector-hive-1.2.2_2.12-1.15.1.jar


# Hive dependencies
COPY hive-metastore-1.1.0.jar /opt/flink/lib
COPY hive-exec-1.1.0.jar /opt/flink/lib
COPY libfb303-0.9.2.jar /opt/flink/lib # libfb303 is not packed into hive-exec in some versions, need to add it separately

# Orc dependencies -- required by the ORC vectorized optimizations
COPY orc-core-1.4.3-nohive.jar /opt/flink/lib
COPY aircompressor-0.8.jar /opt/flink/lib # transitive dependency of orc-core

# add antlr-runtime if you need to use hive dialect
COPY antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar /opt/flink/lib

RUN mkdir ./plugins/s3-fs-presto
RUN cp ./opt/flink-s3-fs-presto-*.jar ./plugins/s3-fs-presto/

RUN mkdir ./plugins/s3-fs-hadoop
RUN cp ./opt/flink-s3-fs-hadoop-*.jar ./plugins/s3-fs-hadoop/

RUN cp ./plugins/metrics-prometheus/flink-metrics-prometheus-*.jar /opt/flink/lib
```

Tnx for the help!

Comment: Please clarify what your docker run commands or compose files look like. What "image" are you referring to?

Comment: Added dockerfile. Is that what you ment? As you can see I add the connector to the lib folder as they mentioned in the documentation

Comment: Your Hive jar copy line is missing /opt/flink/lib. You'll also need all the other jars for Hive mentioned in the Flink docs. Ideally, your container downloads them all using wget rather than copied from your docker context

Comment: In the docs they say "There are two ways to add Hive dependencies. First is to use Flink’s bundled Hive jars. You can choose a bundled Hive jar according to the version of the metastore you use. Second is to add each of the required jars separately. The second way can be useful if the Hive version you’re using is not listed here.

NOTE: the recommended way to add dependency is to use a bundled jar. Separate jars should be used only if bundled jars don’t meet your needs." And I used the bundled jar I don't think I need the other jars no? Can you please specify the jar you mentioned?

Comment: I was only referring to the section of the documentation that shows the file layout including `hive-exec` and `antlr-runtime` JAR, for example

Comment: Sry you're right. I added the jars and update the dockerfile. Now what do they ment by export the "HADOOP_CLASSPATH"? What should be there?

Comment: It's an environment variable that you'd need to set in the container's ENTRYPOINT script... But I would expect the Docker image to have that by default, and you should be able to ignore it.